# Font used in Felix Gonzales-Torres work

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone help me identify the font used in this Felix Gonzales-Torres work? (The numbers in the clock)
[image]

http://www.moma.org/collection/object.php?object_id=81074

Thanks a lot!
Simen.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it's exactly correct, but it looks a lot like [Akzidenz-Grotesk Extended](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/akzidenz-grotesk-bq/):

[image: AG screenshot]

Comment: Very, very close (the serif on 1 and the terminals of 2, 3 and 5 are different). It's quite likely that the original is specially-drawn and unique, so this is probably the best you're going to find.